# Regex to match only the first occurrence of four numbers in a line

Tags: regex

I would like to sort thousands of Bibliographic entries via RegEx. Every entry is build like this:

> Lastname, Firstname. 1900. Title etc.

Now I need a RegEx to match 1900. This works:

```
[0-9]{4}
```

Unfortunately, some titles include more than one four digits group, for example:

> Lastname, Firstname. 1900. Title: 1920-1930. etc.

But I want to match only four digit group (i.e. 1900 but **not** 1920 or 1930).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which regex flavour, which language/tool? There may be a flag/alternative function to stop searching once a match is found.

Comment: I´m planning on using TextWrangler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :

```
(^|\.)\s*([0-9]{4})\s*(\.|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vX0bX6/2)

Comment: Id doesn't work if the digits are at the begining or at the end of the string.

Comment: @kbecker87 This breaks if the title has periods (.) in certain positions – it matches *all* 4-digit numbers with periods and spaces either side, not 'the first 4-digit number'. Whether that's a problem is up to you. http://regex101.com/r/qY3wB6/1

Comment: Until now it works fine, but I just noticed that I have some 300 works that use (19XX) as a indication of year: `Luthe, H.O. (1968).` Those do not get matched... Any idea? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use this:

```
\b\d{4}\b
```

It will match the first occurrence of 4 consecutive digits.

Comment: Couldn't this still match more than once? e.g. a title of `The 1940 XYZ`

Comment: @Shai: No it will match only the first occurrence of 4 digits, because ther're no global modifier.

Comment: By that reasoning OP's regex would also work without modification. So we can only assume that we're working in some kind of implicitly global environment.

Comment: Apologies – just re-read the guidelines and a downvote would be inappropriate (you haven't been 'clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect')! Please edit the answer so it'll let me remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

With this regex, you get only the first four numbers in the text regardless of parentheses.

```
^[^\d]*(\d{4})
```

Explanation:

The regex contains two parts. First part:

- `^` match at the start of the string.
- `[^\d]*` it will match all non-number characters.

These two in combination will match all non-number characters until reach a number.

In the second part of the regex, with

- `()` creates a group, then
- `\d{4}` it matches all digits with a length of four

The first and second part of the regex makes that, only the first four digits to be matched in a group.
Sample [here](https://regex101.com/r/0sKu3s/1)